# git push after deleting few files

Tags: git, github

I am a newbie to git hub. I have created a repo and pushed two files to it. By mistake a new file .README.md.swp is created inside my repo. Now I have deleted two files .README.md.swp and ramu.txt locally after that how can I update my repo on original Github site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these steps

```
git rm .README.md.swp
git rm ramu.txt
git commit -m "cleaning up blah blah"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

After deleting the files run:

```
git add .
git commit -m "files delete"
git push origin master
```

Note that master should be the name of your branch, the default branch name is master

Comment: AFAIK, one would need to do a `git rm` instead of `git add` to remove tracked files.

Comment: but it only shows amit kumar authored please have a look at https://github.com/amitshree/projecteuler

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `git add` use `git rm <filename>` and then commit and push as usual.

You might also want to add `*.swp` to your `.gitignore` file.